# Upgrading consumer from Kafka 8 to 10 with no code changes fails in ZookeeperConsumerConnector.RebalanceListener

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I changed my Maven pom.xml to use the 0.10.1.0 client jar, and without changing any of the client code I ran both a producer and consumer.

The producer added messages to the Kafka 10 cluster fine (verified by kafka-consumer-offset-checker.sh), but the consumers that should have covered the 10 partitions in the topic did not seem to register at all. All partitions are unowned.

The consumer offset and owner output:

```
kafka-consumer-offset-checker.sh --zookeeper localhost:2181 --topic eddude-default-topic --group optimizer-group
[2017-06-28 12:56:06,493] WARN WARNING: ConsumerOffsetChecker is deprecated and will be dropped in releases following 0.9.0. Use ConsumerGroupCommand instead. (kafka.tools.ConsumerOffsetChecker$)
Group           Topic                          Pid Offset          logSize         Lag             Owner
optimizer-group eddude-default-topic           0   28              28              0               none
optimizer-group eddude-default-topic           1   2               2               0               none
optimizer-group eddude-default-topic           2   87              87              0               none
optimizer-group eddude-default-topic           3   0               0               0               none
optimizer-group eddude-default-topic           4   0               0               0               none
optimizer-group eddude-default-topic           5   2               5               3               none
optimizer-group eddude-default-topic           6   80              80              0               none
optimizer-group eddude-default-topic           7   29              29              0               none
optimizer-group eddude-default-topic           8   15              15              0               none
optimizer-group eddude-default-topic           9   0               0               0               none
```

And here is the relevant consumer client error from my app log:

```
2017-06-28 12:55:24,702 ERROR [ConnectorManagerEventPool 1] An error occurred starting KafkaTopicSet 4:eddude-default-topic
kafka.common.ConsumerRebalanceFailedException: optimizer-group_L-SEA-10002721-1498679709599-7154a218 can't rebalance after 4 retries
        at kafka.consumer.ZookeeperConsumerConnector$ZKRebalancerListener.syncedRebalance(ZookeeperConsumerConnector.scala:670) ~[kafka_2.10-0.10.1.0.jar:na]
        at kafka.consumer.ZookeeperConsumerConnector.kafka$consumer$ZookeeperConsumerConnector$$reinitializeConsumer(ZookeeperConsumerConnector.scala:977) ~[kafka_2.10-0.10.1.0.jar:na]
        at kafka.consumer.ZookeeperConsumerConnector.consume(ZookeeperConsumerConnector.scala:264) ~[kafka_2.10-0.10.1.0.jar:na]
        at kafka.javaapi.consumer.ZookeeperConsumerConnector.createMessageStreams(ZookeeperConsumerConnector.scala:85) ~[kafka_2.10-0.10.1.0.jar:na]
        at kafka.javaapi.consumer.ZookeeperConsumerConnector.createMessageStreams(ZookeeperConsumerConnector.scala:97) ~[kafka_2.10-0.10.1.0.jar:na]
        at com.ebay.traffic.messaging.optimizer.impl.kafka.KafkaTopicSet.start(KafkaTopicSet.java:160) ~[classes/:na]
```

I am just using the same Kafka 8 client code I already had and ignoring the deprecation warnings for now. Shouldn't it work as-is?

I could also post details like the configuration properties and code establishing the actual producer and consumer, but I thought I'd first simply ask in case it is an obvious answer.